# how to read captcha images in perl/php?

Tags: php, perl, captcha

Is it possible to read captcha images programatically ? i'm marking this question in perl & php section as of now.

Comment: You might wanna look into something like http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: It's as possible as it is in C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point to captcha images is to come up with something that is *not* machine-readable (easily, at least), so as to prevent script kiddies, poorly behaved robots, and malicious hackers from wreaking havoc on a site's infrastructure.  While there are plenty of solutions for creating captcha images with Perl, there ought not be any for reading them.

There is a module, [WebService::Antigate](http://search.cpan.org/~oleg/WebService-Antigate-0.02/lib/WebService/Antigate.pm) which uses an external source to analyze the captcha, but doing so would almost certainly violate the TOS for the target site.  That could (and probably should) get you into trouble at some point.  Proceed with caution, and be sure to obtain prior authorization (good luck with that!)  :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the point of Captcha is not to allow users to do just that.